# Xamarin: Upload image to server

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need upload image to server using api.
Now I'm using  `System.Net.Http;`

```
byte[] lFileBytes= DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);
ByteArrayContent lFileContent = new ByteArrayContent(lFileBytes,0,lFileBytes.Length);
lFileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("form-data");
lFileContent.Headers.ContentType=new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
lFileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("name","file"));
lFileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("filename", "9.jpg"));
lFileContent.Headers.ContentLength= lFileBytes.Length;
lContent.Add(lFileContent);

    public byte[] ReadAllBytes(string path) {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        streamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        return memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
```

After sending request i have error `Type file is invalid`
I'm thinking problem in  `byte[] ReadAllBytes(string path)`
For request i can use Stream or byte[] 
Please, help
UPDATE

```
 lRequestResponse = await lHttpClient.PostAsync("URL", lContent);
```

Comment: try setting `streamReader.Position = 0` on the first line of the `MemoryStream` block. It could be that

Comment: @user1, streamReader hasn't Position property, maybe memoryStream? but it isn't work;

Comment: Where is your upload code? What method do you use? Also do you have a sample of your server method? does it work from Fiddler?

Comment: @Rohit update upload code, POST.
i hasn't server part.
I use "Postman" for api test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This help me

```
MultipartFormDataContent  lContent=new MultipartFormDataContent();
byte[]  lBytes = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().ReadAllBytes(filename);
ByteArrayContent lFileContent= new ByteArrayContent(lBytes);
lFileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                                            {
                                                FileName = filename,
                                                Name = "imgFile"
                                            };
lFileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
lContent.Add(lFileContent);
HttpResponseMessage lRequestResponse=await lHttpClient.PostAsync(await url, lContent);
```

IFileHelper implement on IOS

```
namespace Client.iOS
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {
        private string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "images", "Databases");

            if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
            }

            return Path.Combine(libFolder, filename);
        }
        public byte[] ReadAllBytes(string filename)
        {
            string path=GetLocalFilePath(filename);
            return (FileStream(path) as MemoryStream).ToArray();
        }
        private Stream FileStream(string path)
        {
            StreamReader lStreamReader = new StreamReader(path);
            MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            lMemoryStream.Position = 0;
            lStreamReader.BaseStream.CopyTo(lMemoryStream);
            return lMemoryStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need, this works for me:

```
var cont = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var image = new StreamContent(img.Image.GetStream());
cont.Add(image, "\"file\"", img.FileName);
var uri = App.apiurl + $"FileUpload/" + img.FileName + "/";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, cont);
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // return error code
    }

}
```