# Xamarin Forms Image to ASP.NET API Controller (Post)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have a controller in my API that requests a `HttpPostedFileBase` as one of the parameters.
I also have a Xamarin Forms application that is going to send out a post request to this API, passing the image as data.  What would be the best way to send an image, I cannot figure out how to convert it.

I'm using the plugin "Xam.Plugin.Media" for the camera, taking the photo with the code below:

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No camera available", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    SaveToAlbum = true
                });

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

                UserPicture.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    var stream = file.GetStream();
                    return stream;
                });
            }
```

The variable "file" that holds the photo is of type "Plugin.Media.Abstractions.**MediaFile**"

If anybody has any advice as to how I would convert this file type to one that can be uploaded to the API, as a HttpPostedFileBase file, that would be brilliant!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676173/xamarin-upload-image-to-server

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!