# Damaged png as result of attempt toupload image to server using MultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload png from my Xamarin iOS app. Server returns code 200 and a link of that image. When I try to copy-paste this link to browser, it shows damaged image template. 
When I try this steps using postman, everything is fine. Server gives me the working link. And I can see my image in browser after copy-paste.

I alredy compared headers from postman many times. Nothing helped. Also I checked if the byte array is valid from my app. Yes it is valid. I have made image from it and displayed it on a mobile.

My request:

```
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "multipart/form-data");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
                imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");

                using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    formData.Add(imageContent, "pic", "picture.png");
                    var result = await client.PostAsync($"{Constants.MainUrl}{"/api/Profile/EditProfilePic"}", formData);
                    var resContent =await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;
                }
```

My byte converting:

```
 using (NSData imageData = _currentImg.AsPNG())
                    {
                        Byte[] imgByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
```

Comment: Hi, here is similar discussion , may be helpful .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676173/xamarin-upload-image-to-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed this code while converting image to byte array. Exactly `System.Runtime.InteropServices...`
Full code below:

`Byte[] imgByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, imgByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));`