# post array as Httpclient multipart/form-data to api

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, mobile

I have an endpoint request me to send an array as part of my body data and below is the code I have using multipart form-data. How do send the array to my endpoint.

```
var file = _mediaFile.Path;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) == false)
{
    var upfilebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);

    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
    var name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);

    baContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(name).Remove(0, 1));
    baContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                {
                    Name = "Image",
                    FileName = name,
                };

    var categorynew = new List<string>();
    categorynew.Add(((Categorypicker.SelectedItem as CategoriesModel).category));

    var categoryArray = categorynew.ToArray();

    content.Add(baContent, "Image", name);
    content.Add(new StringContent(DealerAddr.Text), "DealersAddress");
    content.Add(new StringContent(itemName.Text), "ItemName");
    content.Add(new StringContent(itemDescription.Text), "ItemDescription");
    content.Add(new StringContent(itemPrice.Text), "PreferredPrice");
    content.Add(new StringContent(DealerPhone.Text), "DealerPhone");
    content.Add(new StringContent(DealerCity.Text), "City");
    content.Add(new StringContent(StoreUrl.Text), "SellerWeblink");
    content.Add(new StringContent (categorynew,"Category_Name");
    content.Add(new StringContent((Categorypicker.SelectedItem as CategoriesModel).category), "Category_Name");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(CreateItem, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676173/xamarin-upload-image-to-server) can be helpful .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I later solved this by converting my array back to json before adding it to my content..

```
var categorynew = new List<string>();
categorynew.Add(((Categorypicker.SelectedItem as CategoriesModel).category));

var categoryArray = categorynew.ToArray();
var jsoncategoryArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categoryArray);

content.Add(baContent, "Image", name);
content.Add(new StringContent(DealerAddr.Text), "DealersAddress");
content.Add(new StringContent(itemName.Text), "ItemName");
content.Add(new StringContent(itemDescription.Text), "ItemDescription");
content.Add(new StringContent(itemPrice.Text), "PreferredPrice");
content.Add(new StringContent(DealerPhone.Text), "DealerPhone");
content.Add(new StringContent(DealerCity.Text), "City");
content.Add(new StringContent(StoreUrl.Text), "SellerWeblink");
content.Add(new StringContent(jsoncategoryArray),"category");
```

Comment: Glad to hear that . Thanks for sharing the answer , remember to mark it later when have time  :)

Answer (score 0):

There's, to me, a better solution, that does not need any data content manipulation,
let's say we're waitting the array in a parameter named "Categories"  :

```cs
foreach(var cat in categories)
                mfd.Add(new StringContent(arg, Encoding.UTF8), "Categories[]");
```