# allow arabic text in pdf table using itext7 (xamarin android)

Tags: pdf, xamarin.android, itext7

I have to put my list data in a table in a pdf file. My data has some Arabic words. When my pdf is generated, the Arabic words don't appear. I searched and found that I need itext7.pdfcalligraph so I installed it in my app. I found this code too https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/displaying-text-different-languages-single-pdf-document and tried to do something similar to allow Arabic words in my table but I couldn't figure it out.

This is a trial code before I apply it to my real list:

```
var path2 = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2.ToString(), "myfile2.pdf");
stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
PdfDocument pdf2 = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
            
Document document = new Document(pdf2, PageSize.A4);
FontSet set = new FontSet();
set.AddFont("ARIAL.TTF");


document.SetFontProvider(new FontProvider(set));
document.SetProperty(Property.FONT, "Arial");
 
string[] sources = new string[] { "يوم","شهر 2020" };
 iText.Layout.Element.Table table = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(2, false);
 foreach (string source in sources)
                {
                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(source, Bidi.DirectionDefaultLeftToRight);
                    if (bidi.BaseLevel != 0)
                    {
                        paragraph.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.RIGHT);
                    }

                    paragraph.Add(source);
                    table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1).SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(paragraph));
                }
                document.Add(table);
                document.Close();
```

I updated my code and added the arial.ttf to my assets folder . i'm getting the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'FontProvider and FontSet are empty. Cannot resolve font family name (see ElementPropertyContainer#setFontFamily) without initialized FontProvider (see RootElement#setFontProvider).'
and I still can't figure it out. any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please modify your code so that it's self-contained and is a minimal reproducible sample. Right now it has undefined `tableItems` entries as well as redundant `textView`, `Toast`, `Rsultitem`, commented code.

Comment: please let me know if the edited code is okay

Comment: The error speaks for itself: `FontProvider and FontSet are empty.`. Check the return value of `set.AddFont("ARIAL.TTF")` - according to the documentation the method returns `true` in case font was successfully added and `false` otherwise

Comment: yes it's returning false, I changed my font path to this: ```set2.AddFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.TTF");``` but it's still the same. what should I do?

Comment: Does it return true or false? Does `new File("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.TTF").exists()` return true or false?

Answer (score 1):

**- C #**

I have a similar situation for Turkish characters, and I've followed these
steps :

- Create a folder under projects root folder which is : /wwwroot/Fonts
- Add `OpenSans-Regular.ttf` under the Fonts folder

Path for font is => `../wwwroot/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf`

- Create font like below :

```
public static PdfFont CreateOpenSansRegularFont()
{
    var path = "{Your absolute path for FONT}";
    return PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(path, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
}
```

and use it like :

```
paragraph.Add(source)
         .SetFont(FontFactory.CreateOpenSansRegularFont());  //set font in here

table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 1)
     .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
     .Add(paragraph));
```

This is how I used font factory for Turkish characters ex: "ü,i,ç,ş,ö"

For Xamarin-Android, you could try

```
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Fonts/Arial.ttf");
```

Comment: Hey sir, thanks for responding, but where do i find wwwroot folder for xamarin android, i've used several ways to access the path of my ttf file that is found in my assets folder but i keep getting this exception: System.IO.IOException: my path is not found as file or resource.

Comment: sure sir, I'm constantly changing my code to find a solution, but all the paths I use give me the exception I mentioned. ``` PdfFont arab= PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf");
   document2.SetFont(arab);``` i'm getting it on the path inside my createfont function

Comment: yes sir I tried this too, I added it in my assets folder but I got the same issue

Comment: unfortunately, I couldn't fix it :( it seems that hosting environment is for web. I tried the following: ```string fn = "Arial.ttf";  string fp = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string pc=System.IO.Path.Combine(fp,fn);
                PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(pc);``` but still the same

Comment: Please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676173/xamarin-upload-image-to-server

Comment: For avoiding a long conversation in comments, I had editted my answer, please look at it, and if you still get an error, please share the error stack trace so I can look at the exception.

Comment: okay sir, i'll try the code you mentioned, but how do I share the error stack trace

Comment: it's still there: ```System.IO.IOException: '/data/user/0/com.companyname.app36/files/fonts\ARIAL.TTF not found as file or resource.'``` this is so upsetting :(

Comment: /fonts\ARIAL.TTF needs to be /fonts/ARIAL.TTF

Comment: yes I noticed that, I corrected it but still ```System.IO.IOException: '/data/user/0/com.companyname.app36/files/fonts/ARIAL.TTF not found as file or resource.'
``` :(

Answer (score 0):

Look i fixed it in java,this may help you:

```
 String font = "your Arabic font";
```

//the magic is in the next 4 lines:

```
        PdfFontFactory.register(font);
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font, true);
        PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
        LanguageProcessor languageProcessor = new ArabicLigaturizer();
```

//and look here how i used setBaseDirection and don't use TextAlignment ,it will work without it

```
  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument tempPdfDoc = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile.getPath()), TempWriter);
            com.itextpdf.layout.Document TempDoc = new com.itextpdf.layout.Document(tempPdfDoc);
            com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph paragraph0 = new com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph(languageProcessor.process("الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية--الاستماره الالكترونية"))
                    .setFont(f).setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
                    .setFontSize(15);
```