# Add Arabic to the pdf file iTextSharp

Tags: xamarin.android

Add Arabic language to pdf file using iTextSharplgpl .

Word print code in PDF file
English language appears only and Arabic does not appear Why

code

```
document.Add(new Paragraph("alie جيد جدا"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [allow arabic text in pdf table using itext7 (xamarin android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780908/allow-arabic-text-in-pdf-table-using-itext7-xamarin-android)

Comment: hi Ken White.  I did not find the required one inside the link, and I could not change the language to Arabic

Comment: my new edit not work 'Font f = FontFactory.GetFont("Assets/fonts/DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Phrase p = new Phrase("This is incorrect: هلا بكما ");
p.Add(new Chunk(": 50.00 USD هلا بكم"));
document.Add(p);'

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to below method to create the font from Assets folder.

```
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
string content;
Stream stream = assets.Open("DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf");
var memorystrm = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memorystrm);
byte[] t = memorystrm.ToArray();
if (t != null)
   {
      PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(t, "UTF-8", true);
      ......
   }
```